# SQL UPDATE statement not working

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I am calling a static function to replace a value in .accdb file; to find a value of oldOA, then replace it with newOA.

```
    public static bool updateOA(string oldOA, string newOA)
    {
        ...
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldOA", oldOA);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newOA", newOA);

        command.CommandText = "SELECT [OA_ID] FROM [Operating_Authority_Table] WHERE [OA_Name] = [@oldOA]";
        long value = long.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OA_ID", value);

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Operating_Authority_Table] SET [OA_Name] = [@newOA] WHERE [OA_ID] = " + value;

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            message.show(1, "", "true");
            
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            message.show(1, "", "false");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Initially i simply used:

```
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE [OA_Table] SET [OA_Name] = [@newOA] WHERE [OA_Name] = [@oldOA]";
```

But i was told that I should get the OA_ID, which is the PK and update it from there, there resulting in the above code, but although the function still returns true, the value in the database still isn't updated..

## EDIT

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Operating_Authority_Table] SET [OA_Name] = @newOA WHERE [OA_Name] = @oldOA";
```

I updated to this statement already, though it still returns true, the value does not get updated. Am i making any syntax mistakes?

Comment: if u are supplying a value to the paramter @OA_ID , why are you supplying the value directly in the update statement ?

Comment: because i was told i had to get the PK of the record i was changing, then use the pk in the update statement in order to change that same record..

Comment: I think that is useless. You are getting the PK from the name, so you might as well update the record from the name directly. It will produce the _exact_ same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Operating_Authority_Table set OA_Name = @newOA where OA_ID = (select OA_ID from Operating_Authority_Table where OA_Name = @oldOA)
```

My guess is this can solve your problem

Comment: yes yes yes this works! i suppose this is a "subquery" so i can't actually split it like i did in the question into 2 parts?

Comment: now that it has worked , my guess is the problem was with your parameter OA_ID , you were not supplying it properly.I guess this might also work for you "UPDATE [Operating_Authority_Table] SET [OA_Name] = [@newOA] WHERE [OA_ID] = @OA_ID"

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove the square brackets from the parameters?

Perhaps include your `value` as a parameter as well?

```
UPDATE [Operating_Authority_Table] 
SET [OA_Name] = @newOA 
WHERE [OA_ID] = @myValue;
```

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newOA", newOA);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myValue", value);
```

Comment: it still returns the same problem though. but i solved it through the sub-query part in the other section! thnx!